# Temporarily change identity of running process

Tags: php, macos, posix

I want to temporarily change the identity of a running **root** process.

I have read the way to do this is to first call `setegid` and then `seteuid`.

The problem is that the group somehow is ignored:

```
<?php
# This is executed as root.
var_dump(posix_setegid(61));   # localaccounts(61)
var_dump(posix_seteuid(502));  # bot(502)

$fp = fopen("/tmp/test", "w+b");

system("ls -la /tmp/test");

unlink("/tmp/test");
```

Outputs:

```
$ sudo php -f /tmp/test.php
bool(true)
bool(true)
-rw-r--r--  1 bot  wheel  0 Feb  2 17:49 /tmp/test
```

But I expect it to output:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 bot  localaccounts  0 Feb  2 17:49 /tmp/test
```

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**: It works on a linux machine. Is this some weird OSX quirk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac os x derives from the BSD branch of Unix, and

> According to BSD Unix semantics, the group ownership given to a newly created file is unconditionally inherited from the group ownership of the directory in which it is created.

(From https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier#Effective_user_ID - I can't find a better source)

You can always use `chgrp` to change the group after the file is created